# is there any other way to upload image file in local path location using python lambda function without using flask without getting encoding errors?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, python-requests, multipartform-data, serverless-offline

```
---
import re

def extract_file_content(event):
   
    if isinstance(event['body'], str):
        try:
            file_content = event['body'].encode('utf-8', errors='ignore')
        except UnicodeEncodeError:
            # If encoding fails, replace problematic characters with a placeholder
            file_content = event['body'].encode('utf-8', errors='replace')
    else:
        file_content = event['body']
    
    
    cleaned_content = re.search(b'\r\n\r\n([\s\S]*)\r\n--', file_content).group(1)
    print(cleaned_content)
    
    
    buffer = bytearray(cleaned_content)
    
    return buffer

def save_buffer_as_png(buffer, destination_path):
    try:
        
        with open(destination_path, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(buffer)
        print("Image saved successfully at:", destination_path)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error saving image:", e)


def upload_file(event, context):
    
    buffer = extract_file_content(event)
    
    
    destination_path = r'C:\Users\skirt\lambdaHandler\rectangle.png'  # Save the image in the project folder
    
    
    save_buffer_as_png(buffer, destination_path)
    
    
    with open(destination_path, 'rb') as image_file:
        image_data = image_file.read()

    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'image/png'
        },
        'body': image_data.decode('latin1'),  # Encode the image data to latin1 for binary response
        'isBase64Encoded': True
```

this is my existing code . it succesfully uploading but once i open that it display like file not support the format ,i had attached the iamge of that..                                              kindly suggest any other way for that..

i tried upload that image as it is in the local path ,when i print my event in console it returns like this

```
{'body': '----------------------------865127295699552309414243\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="rectangle.png"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n\r\nPNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00Ñ\x00\x00\x00P\x08\x06\x00\x00\x00Ö�\udc90\x00\x00\x1bòIDATx\x01�\xad�\udc9d[o+[RÇÛvÛIöaæCó4 ñÀ#\x1f\x00!ñ\x00H\x08�\udc90\x100\x19�\xa0¹q¹=gïÄñý~cçRèWÕÕnwìØ;±ÓÎIGZZ�\udc9dmÇ�\udc9d½VýW�\udc9dk\x05A\x10HÞ²\x19B\x10H)nE)\x04E\tR�\udc8dk4ÿ\x1eÿ\x13�\udc8fW!�\udc90�\xa0T�\xa0\x10ÊBD&ó;é®¥?YÈpz/�\udc9d�\udc81\\úãÛõm²�\udc90ï\r&"½Ñ�\udc8dôG7\x12\x14O$\x08ÊR(z�\udc8f0äÞ�\udc81Jï�\udc9d|ü81)ù`,\tô\x05Æ"\t"\x07Ëg¨\x10J¡r&�\xad|¼lJ«?Þx.ÕÆPÚýkiv¯Ö·ÞD½´z39¯õ¥;ÉüV\x14D¥°¢ãP,®\x02h\x05À/0>¯\x08°9²¬U\x10\x19�\udc81>\x04Q[ùw¢9Kp¢\x0fç5é®»×»RoO¤Ñj�\udc8fqÜ:#©\'[{"ãH³3F{\x10s¢b\x11®hGÚÈA´ã@\x1dK%Å%{UÎÅ8ïW¸A¡¨¢Ü�\udc8d\x02¨Ñ\x1dÊÇË¶t3å>µÖX�\udc81\x04âÖ\x1dK#Ù:S¹l¤ZïI«;wï¿¯"e\x18V¤\\.¯r+÷Î9Q\x1er\x10\x1d\x15�\xa0.´H\x1d<Þ¯èM\x11¦{é\x0c§Î\x01�\xa0j³¯ BT�\udc81ã@J\x02ãÎT¿;ÞJ³3ëù½8gÈ#ïs²f,\x1eý0Ì5ÿ\x7f¶Õø�\udc81ê\x02\x11;èWA\x14JP(KµÙfo$½ñLõ\x1c@Ô\x1d.T×Ù\x06"\x0fzªméô\'\n¢ \x08¥R9�\udc8dçw÷ù�\udc8dAt4\x0b\x03(�\udc81\x00Q\x12H\x0f@T:QÎ\x03p�\udc90\x10Õ�\xa0FµöpUlKs�\xa0è\x1cQU¯7¼ñd."\x13}\x06]ä ú�\udc81:Üê\x04�\udc90\x06\x10\x19×t¦Hû¯|¥�\xa0Q=\x08k[\x7fªFO�\udc81´¢ÿ¬\x01\x12z\x13Ü\x08�\udc90ap@/»�\udc81�\udc8d�\udc90blvç\x08Y=o\x0e¢l\tÅA\x11éB\x0e¦p\x00ÎéÉR�\udc81/ñå\x12\x14ËjTP�\udc90�\xa0ï¬\x01È.×�\xa0BèN\x0e¢�\udc81øZ~þË_ë=ÜÔ½v|R�\udc8f¹ö;ÇOüû\x02]\x0e¢l\t \x02\x11\x04ç¹\x13\x01&ÌÎ*j\x15B\tJe\x18x\x01"÷%!Î]¶\x06rÙèJw05�\xa0\x02ÖMb�\udc9d?ëÛ\x01ÊcËA%:N4\x0f)â¬KR\x06jnÖç,¥tú^At-"58�\udc90[ÞÖ\t�\udc9dh³~tÞ\x1cJ£?S1\x10\x11°�\udc9d\x1b«î^DN�\udc8f¾�\xa0H=ê9³\x1cÃ#¸w\x0e¢,\'\x01\x10\x19�\udc90RD\x10çüùNÎNU\x0b\x08Ë9{/�\udc8dñLj�\udc9d\x0fè\t ºh�\udc8d\x14DD/À°�\udc90Õ=ùúÃy\x1bE\x06\x07�\udc8f÷9\'Cå Êr\x0c\x1eÈç#"Râ×\x08¿á\x19\x0be\x13ã°,\x7fý�\udc8fÿ\x00QÂ\x1f\x14ëFÎ�\udc81Òýª³µ7½\x0fÕÆÛ+�\udc8d\\@¤\x1bfÎEºÇu·,Çð\x08î�\udc9d(ËIp\x10å-1\x17¾�\xa0ÇXä�\xa0BaEþû×¿ËñÔº\x00èé Õ{WÊ�\xa0F�\udc8döHãèjõ\x14Kø\x00Q\x02Hñ³¬:³\x1cÃ#¸wbâ|\x15ÌûÇÈ½~\x04Ñ\n�\udc90"b-\nv?ÎÃPÓ3�\udc81\x13uoE>´{�\udc8f\x06\x11â\x1c \x1a^�\udc9dª©@ÔZs�\xa0N×Å\r\x01©9v\x00i\x0e¢\x1d\x06i¯ÀIÞo#XÈ\x00\x0eb\\\x18¹¢gß1ÓvéD>õGÒ,\x1eÑÒb¯s�\xadá\\>5\x06ê#rNÔ\x1b^«\x0e#\x03©\x119\'Ú�\xad_8\x18\x01%é�\xad\x1e»;RÜSR@\t=\x080\x15KfT(i\x1b«\x1a\x1cD-s±\x1e´\n�\udc90]üDnÙó(oÿ\x1fMè\x1b3\x05q¡LîR Å°\x10ëiowÞVp³r\x03&EÄ\'$Ö\x00)\x12ëH¼3b>OµÆÆá(u¢\x7fr\x1fÇ×�\udc81\x08 \x11!Î½K\'ï\x14H1¨@0z\x1c~|^\x05}¾ü\x16OhÃ<\x14\x02�\udc81p\r@¡\x04å÷2¾¾×x7\x12î\x0c\x14÷Ú\x04"\x02[=:¢|\x06�\udc90�\xa08~7<ï/BGñ\x1cGñ\x10ßb�\udc90l\x1bßÇAtú\x0eQ\nÂ-kû«¿ù{µ¤¹ª©\x0e)0<\x19Tî°Mü\x1e\x08\x1097B/Óg)ä\\(Å�\udc81·MrþyjÀö\x0cøÇAäDëµ\x14æ÷ËP\x1fBv\x0c\x04Xô7Öë¤�\udc9d\x7fS�\xadKHD\x04"5t\x04�\udc81`tÈé#w¶fN\x04[@T,Hå\x04n�\udc81!É\\T\'\x0b�\xadE\'r0m\x00\x11)ç\x17�\udc8drA5,\x10K§\x08Ów\x0e�\xa0h\x0cò�\udc81È\x18Üp° R,YÄö-±r�\xad¡F\x17`UÛNDús3\x13ß&ñ9�\udc81j�\xad~¤Eç.?�\udc8d\x13÷r\x10m$Ü\x17\\X¶¨¬\x19¦VK\x01\x10Õ;æÓAÃ\x18�\xa0\x00xj¿\rD\x00h0�\udc9dËüÎ¬t\x00ÚKjeºø\x1cÃÜ-á\x05\tfyÓ\\\x14ð±Ø\x02"R\x114¯§\x10Jw8Ñ$¤\'ÿ©\x00Zû\x7f)±û`\\¨µº\x12ä2\x15Å\x1dH©TÊçÑæ1\x07Q¦+ê\x16\x10©(\x17\x14ÕBÖî�\udc8fä¼ÞVßª\x04®\x05ë9OéS "SVEÈÎ0\x02ÅÑõZ(D!I¾ ¼�\udc9d>\x07ÑqÈô\x0fðJá©æøhÂÜèJA\x04¸\x0f\r"¿\x070l+ï"N´Å ò¶\x00èØADì\x1aÙ¦Ä²�\udc81\x10¯LÌz¾Nô\x00k8\x11EPê�\xad¾\\ÔÚ+\x01©B.ÎE´èA\x04þý?ÒJ<$Ë!Ê¡ì7ºÃX¬{\x00§qþ?\x0e¢¨·\x18º©Të\x1dMÖó¨îÖ�\xad\x1båôû²&�\udc8d:ÑRû�\udc9dï¿Ñ¨j*ñP¤\x11³3V:8Ò^\x01\x04�\udc90R \x0bq\x0f¸�\xa0p2[Óï¬Fvg=Ùß?_I2]M·¿Vo\x0bUx\x10§\x00\x0eÜÈ�\udc9d�\xa0\x06\x11\x05-\x0690nôñÓ¥\x02¨Àî\x11*ÎåÜ(çDÙ¯b\x1bD"ãD\x14\x0civ\x07*N�\udc81¬Úéä0F\x05\x17é#u\x11\x1dZØ\x11\x00Ã�\udc8d0u\x17KV¶Ë<æpæ äÉ,ËEùn\x04r\x17\x04¦~§Ò\nÌt\x0cB©^¶\x14@õE*hqÆ\x1eiáS¹ììÃ°�\xa0Ézé\x1e3:\x05\x1dqî\x0e¤=h\x0f�\udc90¯ÉxE\'ÒP¤×\r"²-1Ò�\udc8d>î2\x1e\x04Â\x054âÄ�\udc90Þ3ï¤\x12J1`2£>.�\udc90\x18jPÀ2\x07xPò\x01�\udc8fµD¥$\x07ùìã4xV�\udc8f\x11\x1fi\x183\x10#á\x1aÕM©a¯Ñ3?ø6pá£ÉG3w_L_î�\udc81×\x0et!�\udc90òIE\x0b\x13òùÙÙYæ\x03»ö9w\x1f�\udc90�\udc8fz~[\t�\xad0£qaªûX]\x03D9êcSÆ\n\x00aÖ®¶ÇÊ�\udc81ê½k-uõìÌÖ-�\xa0cÃ0Jiq\x7f\x01qð~SmIP°]õ6\x16w<�\udc90x�\xad\x7fnLl¶÷H\x1eïÈá¼Û÷ÿðÑ}#N\x04\x01%E9yÀ�\udc8d¸\x14J�\xadÃ�\udc8fÖ}ÿ¸¯�\udc9d+Z°ÞÇ·D°iPÊÉ{5(�\xa0¡¡\x00"D¸%\'ªül\x01Âs�\udc8d\x0f\x1fÎ\x1bºy\x18ÛXz�\udc8do\x05\x11Õ^ý<@GëZnÞVûhÞ²\x05Q\x18R8=\x01\x08gâ\x1c¼äÊ�\xa0Ç\x16vbþ\n®eûü�\udc8f½\x7f\x0cÊ©¸\x18Â^(H£ÙÓ:pìbÜ6\x12îsÙ¹j;U¸1eN«×o\x01 �\xa0\x1dLoTd\x0318\x12»Oüúëóh�\udc8fW\x0fokïïî\x06³\'Â%Æ@2Â,\n\x04h£�\xadPb¢Ad\x10}n"�\udc90q3\x03äë¸n\x13rB¾P¼`jýÂ\x1fÓî\x0c¥Õ�\udc9dhK\x03zsVsî@Ú\x02"@ädèf#æ±{\x01>|µ}L_Ngé>AsIúóc[Ì3^ÉÅ.�\xa0HlqHK\x12=(×�\udc8deòôÊðÎyÖPcãì\x1dC\tËïô=\x7fú©\x18G1E\x1a[�\xa0Äu\x10ØUu¢ù\x03çh\x1al[�\udc8f·\x08\x1f\x11z\x10\x05ï=^�\udc8f\x1en¤\x06¸¤\x16sÃû¼¶ÞæÀÇÿa¤¹ô±ÿoÆ rqèä\x04P\x04²X,äÓ§OR«5¤ÕêH£n�\xadÞè¶z_êÉæ×ißî\x0c¤zÙ\x06é\r�\udc8d\\TÊ�\udc81\x08ñ�\udc81/£¢\\JC´\x0b©û)"\\ò\x7f¶\x08À\x00"t!¸[\tU?vçæÎ\x01ã¾¹Et\x17½[�\udc8dÔ\x12�\xad·¿ù\x00�\udc9df+Î¥m®\x1bÕ\x17\x15<ÓÉ\\�\udc8d®\x0cWÚZ�\xad\x0csi·ÇÚ\x06´Z\x13év§¯»õÆÒM4c�\udc8dÓ5û\x0eE\x00pS·r-@Hcû>æY\tG¢Çè-y�\udc9dÞÇß+�\udc9dÛ{ò®/ßl\x07þh¦�\udc8fO| ÖP"Öý=:ZuGÒëOtq£F9b6sÆâñË¯~=0ñ²u\x08`Æ�\xa0(\x07FÃ+9¿hèK\x00\x1e\x04h\x14.¬\x0f¥ß\x07TÓWÜlA`R¼1�\udc81Ö\x0b= ú42\x04\x10�\udc8fÆ³6Ú\x03mËg÷w@§³�\udc9d÷6÷¦ó¹î÷Ò½?;\x7fz}§Ñò\t�\xa0z\x02XÈ\x01\ro§V{�\udc90\x10Ã3æDî\'©¶\x1béìì½Ìç72\\Ëôj!�\udc8dV_ú©Ôj=étl�\xa0ÕO�\xad�\udc81WÛ\\\\[\x12]\x10\x1a°öê¦;\x01Ì\x7fÿi½®»¥{ÿüX{\x17O�\udc9dÿEQáÕBAä\x00\x03L\x00\tntYkI2b·É:å\x19(\x16ç@ÞQ¬=z\x1eçH(z8\x1d\x01\x10@êõ®\x1b1Y�\udc9d¾m\x05b\x13\x04 Ê×Öo\x06�\udc90®òkA\x04�\udc81ï\x03TO\x03Î\x12Ø<;â-j\x1c3/6\x0f¾@\x1co�\udc8f\x18¢Û¡ïá\x03Ã©Lx\x13Ñ\x19\x00ÇÅT¸º\x1bZ=¥E5>\x14ÊV@Æv\x12ÌV\'rNä}\x12D8�\udc81p::�\udc90�\xa0J.>�\udc90ó¢¾ZØ\nX�\udc815ë5õ&\nù{x¬Úã}?i{ü{\x16÷¶ý;üÞSÚ \x0euS8D©b^Ê4¾\x1f�\udc90ïcáXý\r\n¾�\xa0~¬w¥ÞèfÑ\tnÄbqÙìHo4UÇ÷ßþ�\udc9d?D\x16È´/,cNä�\xa0)\x06f`@/²�\udc90\x1f\x7fPó\x00¤;\n\x17&äo\x14B"uu ãHÉU~ýñ@\x1a�\udc9dd{.7IþÖç\x1fãu«\x1d\x00òÈ\n_å�\udc8f\x15<þ\\l\x0c�\udc90\x1c\x00¤±È¯ÿö\x0fç\x1a+8^\x0bUûDEclCh£�\udc8fÈÇ=\'B\x1fAT`ûEÉAdÕeÂ2¢\x150ä¥¨|3Ìd8{å�\xadj®«\x1e+5Î_O#a4»£\x1a^\x1bØ¯ÖwØ#¡#¡\x1fMæwüx�\udc8dîC�\xa0m\tÚó\x1au�\xa0Åý�\udc8d\t-5I¸/uÈæ÷r=J2\\³¢þ¹q$Ëa)ªl\ng\x02PyË~\x0cæ·¢Q\x0c¾»xççÇÚãÀÆïFïÑ\x18Ô±�\udc90\x1dÔuv¶1eZ§²ÖHw)®Ú\x1eJ�\udc8d\x0b\x19\x14�\udc8f8\rS#"\x1bJ\x1dV\x10c£áJ�\udc90�\xa0éM¼qQ\x0f\\ÕHoµÌQJæ+\x1d�\udc9dqãúbbé\x05Qñx>×t#ìõÙXäBùò\'¿�\udc909s�\udc9dõ\x01hÜ�\udc81»\x17HB¯ñßõ>úýZo(Þ¾©·d´¸vOÎ}i\rgº·§5î`®Æ\x11¬½øª>^4Öoµé�\xa0I÷x½«�\udc9dz¿_ºçÞÞ\x08ñ§¹8Àd8�\udc90°ÎyabPR+\x1e"©P\x1bç\x0e¬wïò\x12·>\x16ì]\x00D�\udc9dn¤×¡·¦�\udc81"ò\x07§¿¿ë¹ÿ®÷)\x105\x06céLfòuµ.ç�\xad®tÆì\x0cØ�\udc8fõ¾t\x06s\x19oÕmB\x14\x0c\x1683][èK=¶¸�\xadª=®ËëØâñF\x16Ìªg·7Zì�\udc81�\udc8f\x06\x01\x10ùªFJr«�\udc9d�\udc8fÌiñm>Â¸.4Ç\x18\'x9\x0fl=$\x11½õßÞ\x19D»b�\udc8fßÃØAë\x0cgº@;\'j\x0e®4þ�\udc8fýi§W7rYkk\x7frú�\udc9dXúqcÂ:\x10�\xadÌûÖ\x00EGø�\udc81ze©\x11�\udc90tûÄ\x14\x08¿#Èìôf\x1d±èîä\x0b\x02 ^nE¼K³Þü<æÖ+ðÄqy\r B]\x00Dô\x07Ndæì©|ª6cîãî\x14å@\x05¸Qr�\udc81^åD+c×�\xa0(zFM£\x13»\x12¤Y¼®"Ô\x16è\x0c�\xadÒM$â}ýñB£yYÒ%H�\udc8fËq Y$ø#/þD¢Y\x19¼ü7â?[Å¹=s%�\xad¤Mü¾\x14-úlê\x0bj�\udc8dcS|o<ÓjIµvOtß\'\x059pVÓS¶�\udc90QÖ!3Îné\x03³T\x1cÙÉ\x1a�\udc8f\x03\x02áJdz\x12(¸\x0c»\'\x0bÖ¬xp\x0e¤�\xa0·Lþ\x1e\x16\x01\x1f÷l@\x04Ü·å`Z\x05\x11;\nFÄå\x16C|@\x14èg3é�\xa0h»³k6±åu%ý@;ÑPÖ!\x1aÛ@ä\x06\x00Æ �\udc90]In\x0eH{�\udc90(&\x18±ÞÉÜ¸Óá\ti§�\udc81Þ\x03�\udc81\x1eã}\x02D½^\x04&ä\x05(I�\udc9dI§·�\udc90Zc"½áB£Y.\x1b}5_\x17Ê¤¶ÅóäÌvEÇ\nêz´%x.-À�\udc8f½Æ;i4®!ø¥�\udc8f×qä5@ó\x0bó7r�\xadçù\x03">3-(á\x14�\udc90]\x19±ä+�\udc81áÑ\x01ø\x12÷K½ó±¨Ù©ºÄT£Ò\x0bûß\x02�\xa0RQ7q\x06<a¥$-¸\n~Ê%�\xa0¶%\x04KÈC\x16½Å�\udc81ëçkûHÆu+Z\x14£PüOçµe`�\xa0Éµ\x0e*K\x01¶Â\'ntHfÔú ¹U�\udc8fó\\$Ü�\udc8d».ú£\x1f\x7f!½>�\udc81¦øZLj@X;{Ó�\udc8f\x089\x1aFq\x7fÄñõÕ�\udc8fC`rµ>�\udc90vo&µæH¦×"}\t(\x1b:2\x1ah�\udc8dÃ�\udc8f]D£Â:ê»óraZA*2Ù4\x0b\x1853dR´{pÜ¨WÙýJô| ÔÑøZ�\xadPâöÿñcCu*Å" V;gÙ\x0e$�\udc8fª\x058þ\x03+ï·�\udc81ÉÆø\x7f¾øº!�\udc90]©Ô�\xa0\x11\x00\x04Õ#·âþÜ\x0fý\x19juðª#\x15\x10\x01 êr\x18mx4Ì¶w[óù:\x10�\udc81²lî\x0fZö\x16:¿ëÀó\x7ft\x15p¾\x10�\udc8dù@¼c_\x1f·¶8\x18Uû¹÷p(ç>Îr\x0bß\x1a"J�\xadÜnÅúÅÿþJ#L0úh`po¢)\x06»ÎãS¿ÙT\x06×ÑyhñB¾þ¦&WW÷röî{+\x11\x08Î=}îwêÓ�\xa0ñsÆ#+\x0eÄ}á$\x1e½ì�\xad0Ç\x03N\x14}?}\x1d+\x1d¬ügÂÂ�\udc90\x10ét÷m5c.\x02À\x00\x16çB\x0e\x1c\x06\x14n\x03h9V�\udc8f\x13\x19t¾øòç*Îáwa. ntÙ§c×ÿc\x07õÉµÈE}$\x17õ�\udc81g4½\x7fù·\x1fGÖ[«HäÓÓS\n�\udc81Xu(Óçv|O\x07Mº\x07D(èY6¸Ès¯<È�\udc81$�\udc81X\t)<AÃ|q¯f5�\udc9dÌÚòþý{«ë\x10�\xadª\x00\x08N\x04R¾3öÄ\x15\x14,d×Ø½\x02©@\x1dÎ)êL¥Ú\x18ËE},�\xadÎ\\\x06£{ùý\x1fêR\x08ÉAÃx�\udc90L¬·\x035I\x0f�\udc8f.\x12i�\udc90¤�\udc8f¡!äGã\x08/ß/\x13èV\x13Ó\\iûuÓ\x1dÌ4²Zïé\x1e:L"�\udc81«\x17ÕöÄÞ¹X\x07\x07\x020\x1ekÇqël\x12ù\x1e\x1dì\x08�\udc90o�\xad;hwóýüºh1w¶\x19¥\x15ìÊQô½ÎT&3jýJÆSÑ\x16\x04øz,ö�\udc8d\r¸Vë[\\ t\x15LF\x17�\udc8f,\x18i�\udc90¤�\udc8fw\n/°zgÕ/u!{ô9%¥65¾\x0b¨�\udc81�\udc8f8(¸VméO´¸\x04\x16#8Òh4\x11þ rÄ5UÃ¢q ¿Fïâ]\x1aXo\r\x1c»¿¯9º1,0Ö4\x02D9]÷f[:�\xa0cÀufR�\xad_K�\xady+_þÒUßBHì[Ùö�\udc8d\x08ÞM×l\x18`gINÊ§Ñn\x10,¨ë\x15]K&}\x0eÈÉÉºQ\x04�\udc90gH÷»<×âÎriÈgÑ¼¢;û-¸\x0f�\xadöÎú»;ÅP,²1F(\x18\x14Ì$îÜþ«¯þ/þ_ÿ�\xad¼·±L�\udc8f\x03c|5»QÃ\x0eú\x10ûñb\x7f.ÖÆnÎ¤ÑÉ\x0fþì/%\x08\x00�\udc8fár\x17?çBÆ\x00E ^û\x1c�\xa0\na\x0c¤äÜ¯\x1c§A>7:ò¡c�\xad\x1fY%â\'=Ùø\x1f\x7f�\udc9dÿX<Ú\x0fþô�\udc8f�\xadÎ\x18\x05*Ú#uÒÑ£\x7fQ>\x17Ç/q\x7f\x10Hs®Ó�\xad\x1fâ¸\x11½XøK*J;_Þ;]8d½\x04°üþî?\x050H\x0f�\xadé³Û�\udc8fÇÃÑ\x08Ùiõ(\x03p�\xad\x11\x08õöt\x067Úø^ìûçßçÛ\x17É\x17éý¦o³×�\udc9d�\xa0,\x16\x02_Rx&åÊ{\tgòÕ¯>¨ß\x01«\x0f1XÃé½|sÑÑ¼§ÖðFS8pÜ8ãç/Õ{â÷�\udc8dµÕ�\udc81\x12¢PzE\x7f.xîÿ·G2ÜÈE�\xad«c�\udc8dhü<õ\x16;óM¥7º\x13À\x05®Õëñ\x1fÿÉ_HPÀÒÆbù"@yì>?Àc\x0fw�\xa0�\udc8flá8rH(REÇ&¦,³?R\x11\x11\x07\x1e!#XÜ\x1f¡ùW)�\udc8f<@rð¸)Þ�\udc8f�\udc8f¦?2\x101Nøy0K[ViK\rE\x1ex\x0c¨.j}\x05Õpr\'ï´bø}]èLôÊ3\x7f\x03\x03åñ÷[:�\udc9d\x13\'ÅB\x01UY\r\x16(�\udc8d¬l¹â\x0c¨6�\udc81eÓõÌ�\udc81td b\x1c1\x0c!Ò1¶ãOÕ¶\x1a\x00\x16î\x0b®¡÷øv²4c§ü\x7f\x19q¥Ç,£z1`y¯ZmÔÜM|²Ø*\x17Æ[Î£P�\udc8f®ï¤Õ3=\x01+FG!IY\'8®½ÿsÅ�\xad\x03ÿ?¢rot£\x1cÜ\x17\x1e@5ÌÕÊw~ÙÑt¡\x0bm§³Ü\rd�\udc9d\x13=#z�\udc8dAT.±Õ&\x19þ\x0fÄXñ9\x00*,)E�\udc8d\x07ZØO9Kzu?¦ó\x03�\xa0¹Ìf¢\x0e\x00\x10¢2¿×\x1d]\t�\xa0�\udc81ßG\x04n°ì¢Dª\x06�\udc81f¯\x0f±�\xa0¿m\x10±é0\\rÆ^ÒØ7"fl<csÂón¾¸þ2K\x16±ìÄä«©\x1fºw+Vº�\udc8f¹Ò¨;\\¨õ\rÕ\x13îep2»�\udc8dö?B\x12°P\x1d\x0bü|G\x16(ü¶AT)â\x10 ?V0á\x0f\x16ôiHP!�\udc90Å½ÄE7*8è\x0f\r ~?\r\x1e?\x7f- J&]¢k\x02 Äåù�\udc9dX�\udc81Dt/Ë9anÑn">O\x19ö®P¿Å~uR6M\x02 ò\x08\x06_\rU(\x14\x15Hq\x11ô\x16\x19ä¸ X~ËÒäìéËû�\xadÔx¬¡¸\'\x1d\x0ev\x05`Âx(À³pOÒ\x140Äp\x1f\tðø³é\x18E\x0eÔ|\x0b¸\x1a\x1eF�\xa03?I\x1dãMsöÂ×ß"xï¼ÛD$¹\x02lH*bÌ,X§Ia\x03Â�\udc90Úº»\x00²ýáAäÎPwü®Ê\tÕ9ãK¼"µ¾uÇq^�\udc81\x01Å±è\x10é@Ä\túO±bÆ�\udc9duæë#\x05QÚ¤ûÎ#0©èfbN{L\x15ÕÂ5ÖÒÆ~]E\r«\x0fÎäC\x04ÔÈc\x17\x01D\x12v\x14�\xa0?d£¢5vt{¸©\x16ÄI$\x05Ñ¸äÒ\x04Ô¡8Qò\x1ep\x1f\x1a÷\x02\\ô\x04«V\x1b�\xad(Å?¹¸\x15¥r\nV\x17¹\x1cDqhÆ\x01Uk-[�\udc81ru´&�\udc8fq¾jUÄçZÜPû�\udc908æìGÇ\\£i\x11ô&\'\x07k<\x1f\x16+�\xadS÷)TtG�\udc8fp\x10%�\udc81$ðäõ}\x1es\x0fë>\x07®\x15\x1dË�\xadö.¼OT\x0eú5èsÒ\x0e¾�\xadßeo\x1eÞm]O¦&yüø-SÓ|VW¹N±r¦Q±.âN«åVWV\x13O\x0ep-�\udc8d9CÂYCé\x0cÆºõL\x1aDé�\xadDö\täo9÷�\udc81|\rx\x1cLãë{�\udc8d<P�\udc90DõÃE^ë�\xa0iNtçO\t4ü¶ü�\udc8fª¾B|ÙC¥ÿ²Å.j×òñ²)lEÈêYmtÖ\x0fç5]E\x01ûüxé\x08<\x00h\\\x04<é\x16\x7f\x06\n"ÄI\x07s\x02\x11ú�\udc90d.òfl�\xa0�\xa0\x19Ø·h�\udc90¢�\udc90$y�\xa0Hq�\udc81�\udc8d�\udc8f¸pÞÖ5¯1AMr?^ö¥~s{t�\xadÅ�\udc90¿¾hJw²�\udc90c\x0c\x08\x17ÕæX°zÒ2KèKIkªe\x0f"\x0c\x1bj\x1du¤bLøç\x7fýO\t\n\'\x12}OAÄ¡çTHK\x08¤\x1c\x16u#l\x0c9|¶$ÜMÑªÎ´üþ\x0b^\x7f[yÈi%¸ìx\t \x07U£?Ö@A\x068\x06\\Xzý¡T«U¹¿\'\r�\udc9d&ÎÅØ\x1c¾ëöÔï=\x00\x10\x1cê88\x11¢�\udc9dVáD9å@å÷\n$Õ\x1d\x15@iì ¢÷±\\öÇ\x0b¢ÿ\x07fwêÆ\x1a\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND®B`\r\n----------------------------865127295699552309414243--\r\n', 'cookies': [], 'headers': {'user-agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.36.3', 'accept': '/', 'postman-token': '2fb1717b-0ef0-49b7-9bab-d9c09331047a', 'host': 'localhost:3000', 'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------865127295699552309414243', 'content-length': '7421'}, 'isBase64Encoded': False, 'pathParameters': None, 'queryStringParameters': None, 'rawPath': '/upload', 'rawQueryString': '', 'requestContext': {'accountId': 'offlineContext_accountId', 'apiId': 'offlineContext_apiId', 'authorizer': {'lambda': {}, 'jwt': {}}, 'domainName': 'offlineContext_domainName', 'domainPrefix': 'offlineContext_domainPrefix', 'http': {'method': 'POST', 'path': '/upload', 'protocol': 'HTTP/1.1', 'sourceIp': '::1', 'userAgent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.36.3'}, 'requestId': 'offlineContext_resourceId', 'routeKey': 'POST /upload', 'stage': '$default', 'time': '18/Mar/2024:13:38:04 +0530', 'timeEpoch': 1710749284614}, 'routeKey': 'POST /upload', 'stageVariables': None, 'version': '2.0'}
```

but want to remove the unwanted portions and then which method is suitable to encode and get the correct file content then i want to upload the actual image file into the local path

Comment: What do you mean by "upload"? Are you referring to Amazon S3? Or is this a Lambda function for API Gateway? Please Edit your Question to add more context.

Comment: no iam trying to upload the png image file via formData using postman in a local path location.